# lxml can not see the attributes of parsed tag

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse a picture link, which is located under 'src' attribute in 'img' tag [here](https://www.allsole.com/trainers-clothing-men-footwear/arkk-copenhagen-men-s-asymtrix-mesh-trainers-off-white-ash/12024279.html)

here's source html code from browser:

```
 <img class="athenaProductImageCarousel_image" data-hide="false" alt="ARKK Copenhagen Men's Asymtrix Mesh Trainers - Off White Ash" aria-role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" src="//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/1600/1600/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg" srcset="//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/20/20/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 20w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/600/600/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 600w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/270/270/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 270w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/70/70/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 70w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/300/300/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 300w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/480/480/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 480w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/50/50/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 50w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/60/60/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 60w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/180/180/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 180w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/1600/1600/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 1600w,
 //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/130/130/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 130w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/960/960/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 960w, //s1.thcdn.com/productimg/100/100/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 100w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/200/200/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 200w, 
//s1.thcdn.com/productimg/350/350/12024279-9854653309695274.jpg 350w">
    </div>
```

and here's what I get with lxml:

```
<img class="athenaProductImageCarousel_image" data-hide="true" alt="ARKK Copenhagen Men's Asymtrix Mesh Trainers - Off White Ash" aria-role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"/>
</div>
```

I don't know why, I'm just using this code:

the element is the lxml tag object parsed with lxml

```
element.xpath('//img[@class="athenaProductImageCarousel_imagePreview"]')[0]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a little more?

Comment: your xpath doesn't fit to your html. You can't get it.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add item then you may not get items because `lxml` can't run JavaScritp.

Comment: @party-ring added some more explanations, but if you need more plz ask me

Comment: I don't see your HTML in html from server - even in browser. Maybe they send different content for different devices/browsers or they use JavaScript to add this items.

Comment: @furas that's the issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be difficult to debug without having access to the entire HTML.
Are you sure there is only one `athenaProductImageCarousel_image` on the page ?

Also, you are using a different class `athenaProductImageCarousel_imagePreview` in lxml

```
element.xpath('//img[@class="athenaProductImageCarousel_imagePreview"]')[0]
```

Is that deliberate ?

Comment: I can provide you a link of the item: https://www.allsole.com/trainers-clothing-men-footwear/arkk-copenhagen-men-s-asymtrix-mesh-trainers-off-white-ash/12024279.html I'm trying to parse image url

Answer (score 1):

Is there any other img elements on this with the same class?

Take a look if there isn't any other elements in the return of element.xpath

Another think, it seems that you are using the wrong class.

what you want:

```
element.xpath('//img[@class="athenaProductImageCarousel_image"]')[0]
```

Comment: but it doesn't show the 'src' tag with img url inside, for any class